# Hide Menu when table is null php laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to hide menu **My Profile** when **lender** table is empty/null .but show menu when table is not null/not empty in laravel 5.

I stack just in here, because I dont know how to do next. So far just nothing happened.

```
@if($lender != null)
                            <li>
                                <a href="{{ url('account/profile-lender') }}">
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
                            </li>
@endif
```

Maybe any php code idea?
thanks in advance

Comment: what is the output of $lender ??

Comment: output of $lender is empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@if(!(count($lender) == 0))
   //if not empty code
@else
   //if empty code
@endif
```

Comment: Can you please share your db query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@if(!empty($lender))
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('account/profile-lender') }}">
                                <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
                        </li>
@endif
```

If this does't works. Then provide the output for this:

```
print_r($lender);
```

Comment: this code is really works for me to hide menu. but its also hide the menu when table is not empty

Comment: What is the output of `$lender`. Please provide that.

Comment: output of $lender is []

Comment: check with this condition
@if($lender instanceof /App/Lender)

Comment: @ardigunawan Your `$lender` variable is returning empty and hence the Profile will not be show in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

if your `$lender`is a collection class you can do as follow

```
@if(!$lender->isEmpty())
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url('account/profile-lender') }}">
           <i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile </a>
    </li>
@endif
```